# Route53 aws: GEO routing with custom path CloudFront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I have to configure a DNS table to route traffic in different paths of a CloudFront distribution.
example:
www.mydomain.com, policy geo ITALY, CNAME d1111111.cloudfront.net/IT/index.html
www.mydomain.com, policy geo IRELAND, CNAME d1111111.cloudfront.net/IE/index.html

Route 53 does not consider /it/index.html.
Other solutions?

Comment: Nothing in DNS ever modifies paths.  But... uh, does the [`Cloudfront-Viewer-Country` header](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/enhanced-cloudfront-customization/) not provide a suitable solution?

Answer (score 0):

A path is relevant to the HTTP protocol. DNS is a separate protocol and is only concerned with DNS to IP conversions.

The use of geo routing is not entirely correct in this case. GEO routing is intended to route a client to the closest datacenter, not present different content. This already happens with cloudfront anyway.

Instead you should handle this within your by either doing an IP lookup or using the browser locale. Sometimes the detection is wrong and a user should have the ability to manually change the auto detection. If the user changes thier locale, it should persist for the entire session.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In the description it is specified that when you use geolocation routing, you can localize your content and present some or all of your website in the language of your users.

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-policy.html#routing-policy-geo

Comment: You can, but this generally means that you are going to a different site all together. Some companies do have different sites for different regions, rather than just localizing them.